# How to pass a variable to javascript in nested function

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have several protractor / angularjs it blocks that repeat the same bit of code that I would like to put inside a function. I want to just call the function instead of repeating this over and over.

```
it('should move directly to Draft', function() {
  posting_sum_page.locate_action_button.click();
  posting_action_page.move_action.filter(function(elem) {
    return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
      return text === 'Draft';
    });
  }).click();
});
```

This part of the block is the repeated part I want to create a function for. I am new to javascript so this is eluding me on how to do this.

```
return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
      return text === 'Draft';
    });
  }).click();
```

I need to be able to substitute 'Draft' with different variables. I am using page objects for part of this and I am not sure A) how to create a function like this and pass in my text & B) if it should go on the spec side or the page side? This is probably pretty basic for most folks. But since I am new to javascript I am having trouble wrapping my head around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would *extract the whole filter function* into a "helpers" module.

helpers.js:

```
var Helpers = function () {
    this.filterByText = function (text) {
        return function (elem) {
            return elem.getText().then(function(actualText) {
                return actualText === text;
            });
        };
    }
}

module.exports = new Helpers();
```

Usage in the test:

```
var helpers = require("helpers");

describe("My Test", function () {
    it('should move directly to Draft', function() {
        posting_sum_page.locate_action_button.click();
        posting_action_page.move_action.filter(helpers.filterByText('Draft')).click();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input. alecxe your solution worked best. Much appreciated to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
describe('...something...', function()
{
  var clickBtn;


  beforeEach(function()
  {
    clickBtn = function(testText)
    {
      return posting_action_page.move_action.filter(function(elem) 
      {
        return elem.getText().then(function(currentText) 
        {
          return currentText === testText;
        });
      }).click();
    };
  });


  it('should move directly to Draft', function() 
  {
    posting_sum_page.locate_action_button.click();
    expect(clickBtn('Draft')).toEqual('...something...');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the return block only

```
it('should move directly to' + targetText, function() {
  posting_sum_page.locate_action_button.click();
  posting_action_page.move_action.filter(function(elem) {
    checkSameText(elem, targetText);
  }).click();
});

function checkSameText(el, targetText) {
    return el.getText().then(function(text) {
      return text === targetText;
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what the page object type is for `posting_action_page.move_action` but what I think you are looking for is using [by.buttonText](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.buttonText) or [by.linkText](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.linkText).

```
// html: <button>Draft</button>
element(by.buttonText('Draft')).click();

// html: <a href="">Draft</button>
element(by.linkText('Draft')).click();
```

There are other locators that might be helpful like `by.partialButtonText` and `by.partialLinkText`.